# How to fix "'blob' package not found" when installing RSQLite?

Tags: r, rsqlite

I want to use the RSQLite package, but when I try to use the library, I get this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RSQLite’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘blob’
```

Is there a way to fix this?

I've tried updating the RSQLite Library which did not change anything, and 
I tried installing the blob package, but it did not work.

It said "Warning in install.packages
  installation of package ‘blob’ had non-zero exit status"

I tried to install the RSQLite package using:

```
install.packages("RSQLite")
```

and this was the output:

```
Installing package into C:/Users/malik/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4
(as lib is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ellipsis, rlang, vctrs, blob


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
         binary  source needs_compilation
ellipsis  0.1.0 0.2.0.1              TRUE
rlang     0.3.4   0.4.0              TRUE
vctrs     0.1.0   0.2.0              TRUE
blob      1.1.1   1.2.0             FALSE
RSQLite   2.1.1   2.1.2              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/ellipsis_0.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 30847 bytes (30 KB)
downloaded 30 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/rlang_0.3.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1080437 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/vctrs_0.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 499748 bytes (488 KB)
downloaded 488 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/RSQLite_2.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2097863 bytes (2.0 MB)
downloaded 2.0 MB

package ‘ellipsis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘RSQLite’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\malik\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOsEBnR\downloaded_packages
installing the source package �blob�

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/blob_1.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 9355 bytes
downloaded 9355 bytes

* installing *source* package 'blob' ...
** package 'blob' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'vctrs' 0.1.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'blob'
* removing 'C:/Users/malik/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/blob'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\malik\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\malik\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOsEBnR/downloaded_packages/blob_1.2.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘blob’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\malik\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOsEBnR\downloaded_packages’
```

When I try to use the RSQLite Library, I get this error:

I wanted to use the library, but it won't let me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

```
library(remotes)
install_github("cran/blob")
install_github("cran/RSQLite")
```

It worked for me.........

Comment: This answer worked for me. For anyone else seeing this -  I'm using R 3.3.3 via RStudio.